# chain trigger the select events the same way a user might after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, chain

I am creating a form which has chain select element. What I am actually having trouble with, is the following:

After selecting an option from the select box, the second select box is being populated from the database. Example:

**Category Select Element (Output)**

```
 <select  name="category" class="form-control selectcategory" id="category">
    <option value="0" >Select Category</option>
    <option value="17" >Motors</option>
    <option value="18" >For Sale</option>
</select>
```

**Sub-category element generated from database after selecting a category (Output)**

```
    <select  name="subcategory" class="form-control select category" id="subcategory">
        <option value="0" >Select Category</option>
        <option value="17" >Cars</option>
        <option value="18" >Bikes</option>
    </select>
```

After the form is submitted, errors will be displayed if there is any but then the form is being reset and the visitor has to select all the options again.

I managed the keep the category selection after the form is submitted but the subcategory is reset to blank.

Is there any way to trigger the category select element after the form is submitted as if a visitor selects it so the subcategory will load again possibly with visitor's selection?

Regards

Comment: Both your selects have the same id. Elements can have the same class but the id must be unique. How are you submitting the form? Via ajax or good old fashioned reload the whole page after submitting?

Comment: I’d is different on each select. I made a mistake while I was posting here. I am submitting the form by reloading the page.

Comment: What does your php for handling the form look like?

Comment: At the moment php is not handling anyting the form is still in html format using java to trigger the chain action.

Comment: your solution can be a quite simple .. on change of select store the selected values in localstorage and if the values exists on page refresh just pick them from local storage and select the sub selection dropdowns

Comment: Do you also have sample java code as i dont know java much, i mainly work with php.

Comment: @Dalyan have to write a complete snnipet for that .. could take 10 min for me .. ok with that ??

Comment: That will be highly appreciated.